# Finding what is common to two arrays

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to compare two arrays and show what is common to both of them?

```
array1 = ["pig", "dog", "cat"]
array2 = ["dog", "cat", "pig", "horse"]
```

What do I type to show that `["pig", "dog", "cat"]` are common between these two arrays?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can intersect the arrays using `&`:

```
array1 & array2
```

This will return `["pig", "dog", "cat"]`.

Comment: For other operations on sets, like union and division, see the [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) class.

Answer (score 9):

Set Intersection. Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, with no duplicates, like:

```
["pig", "dog", "bird"] & ["dog", "cat", "pig", "horse", "horse"]
# => ["pig", "dog"]
```

You can also read a blog post about [Array coherences](http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/array-coherences)