# Rails match 2 arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models Donation and BankDeposit

Donation has a column sender_id

Bank Deposit has a column donated_by_id

So let say I have:

```
@donations = Donation.all
@bank_deposits = BankDeposit.all
```

and these 2 arrays return this values for mentioned columns:

```
@donations.sender_id = [1,3,6,8,9]
@bank_deposits.donated_by_id = [2,3,7,8]
```

In this example, assuming ids of donations are 1 to 5, result I want to achieve is selecting rows with id 2 and 4 (as they contain 3 and 8 present on bank_deposits.donated_by_id).

How should I implement the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **ONLY** need the donations you can change the code and try:

```
@donations = Donation.where(sender_id: BankDeposit.pluck(:donated_by_id))
```

If you want to keep both and use all the records just filter using `select`:

```
bank_deposit_donated_by_ids = @bank_deposits.map(&:donated_by_id)
matched_donations = @donations.select do |elem|
  bank_deposit_donated_by_ids.include?(elem.sender_id)
end
```

Didn't test the syntax/API, but that's the idea.

Comment: This one works and achieves the result I'm looking for. I'll keep trying before accepting an answer as I guess the other answer would be better as it's simpler..

Comment: the important thing is to understand what's going on this code.

The first simply fetches the donations where the donator is also at `bank deposit` table.

But if you need all the other records you perform two queries, the second solution gets all results and filter with what you want using ruby [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-select) built-in methods.

Comment: Yes this one very clear thanks a lot.. I was already suspecting I had to use pluck or map but I wasn't sure about the correct syntax. I just want to fully understand the other answer before judging which one I should accept.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
@donations.sender_id & @bank_deposits.donated_by_id
```

This will give you output of common element id from the both array after that you can filter it in any sense you like.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But I don't get how this one could possibly return what I'm looking for..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533186/finding-what-is-common-to-two-arrays YOU CAN SEE THIS

Comment: 2.3.0 :001 > a = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.3.0 :002 > b=[2,3,4,5]
 => [2, 3, 4, 5] 
2.3.0 :003 > a&b
 => [2, 3] 
2.3.0 :004 >

Comment: see i tried in my console with sample array and its works .

Comment: Although this solution is nice in its simplicity I can't get it to work on real example with instances, while answer below worked at first try..

Comment: It does not work, I keep getting undefined method sender_id for #... I think I am giving up. Did you ever try this outside console with real instance variables?