# How to check if array shares elements with another array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to see if an array of records shares elements with another array.

I'm using the splat operator for a conditional like this:

```
if @user.tags.include?(*current_tags)
    # code
end
```

This works when tags are present, but returns this error when `current_tags` are empty.

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

This happens a lot in my app so I was wondering if there are any alternatives to achieving this same functionality but in other way that won't blow up if `current_tags` is an empty array.

Comment: this will only work if current_tags has exactly 1 element. I would recommend not using `include?` here

Comment: What's the expected behavior if `current_tags` is empty – should the conditional evaluate or skip the code block in that case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding what is common to two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533186/finding-what-is-common-to-two-arrays)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use an intersection to solve this problem instead. The intersection of two arrays is an array containing only the elements present in both. If the intersection is empty, the arrays had nothing in common, else the arrays had the elements from the result in common:

```
if (current_tags & @user.tags).any?
  # ok
end
```

Comment: All the answers were good, but this is the simplest, easiest to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another trick to do the same is:

```
if current_tags.any? { |tag| @user.tags.include?(tag) }
  ...
end
```

if you want to be sure that at least one of the `current_tags` is in the array of `@user.tags`, or

```
if current_tags.all? { |tag| @user.tags.include?(tag) }
  ...
end
```

in case all tags should be there.

Works fine with empty `current_tags` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition if `current_tags.present?`

```
if current_tags.present? && @user.tags.include?(*current_tags)
    # code
end
```

As

```
2.3.1 :002 > [].present?
 => false
```

Comment: This doesn't work if current_tags has more than 1 element - `include?` takes 1 and only 1 arg